# Does 5V DC power supply require Ground wire?

Tags: electrical, grounding

I got this 5V DC 8A power supply for some 5V LED strips.  For the AC input connections it has Line, Neutral, and Ground (numbers 1, 2, and 3 in attached image).

My question:  For the 120V AC input is the Ground required or optional?

This project (power supply and LED strips) will be installed indoors.

[image]
[image]

[Amazon link to the power supply.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B019RNKK7I)

Comment: Note that screw #3 on that last picture is for ground

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ground connection is a safety feature, and should be connected.

If something breaks internally in the power supply or wiring which causes the case to be energized, the ground connection means it'll blow the breaker/fuse and power will be shut off.

Without it, the case can become energized with no indication anything is wrong until someone touches it (at which point they can be electrocuted).

Comment: Even then.. with stuff like this that is sitting isolated on a bench... I always touch it very lightly with caution just in case.